# gmaps.js | Remove old marker when a new marker is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps.js

I am trying to create a location input field where in a user will select a location. So **there should be only one marker present** on the map.

**My current code adds a marker on click:**

```
    var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#m_gmap_2',
        zoom: 16,
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.028333,
        click: function(e) {
                     var lat = e.latLng.lat();
                     var lng = e.latLng.lng();
                     map.addMarker({
                                lat: lat,
                                lng: lng,
                                title: 'College Location'
                     });
        },
    });
```

But I cannot figure how to remove previous marker within `click()` or `addMarker()` function.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the previous marker so you can remove it when you add a new one. For example:

```
var marker;
var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#m_gmap_2',
    zoom: 16,
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333,
    click: function(e) {
        if( marker ) marker.setMap( null );
        var lat = e.latLng.lat();
        var lng = e.latLng.lng();
        marker = map.addMarker({
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng,
            title: 'College Location'
        });
    },
});
```